# Suggestions for *nix framework to write a menu interface

Tags: linux, user-interface, frameworks

I am going to write a full-screen menu interface to run on Linux and *BSD which is controllable primarily by a game pad and wanted suggestions for a language/framework that is well suited to this problem. Each menu item will launch an external program.

It would preferably be easily theme-able, and load menu data from text files, perhaps in the form itemName: "command -to -execute".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Qt for Embedded Linux](http://qt.nokia.com/products/platform/qt-for-embedded-linux/) is a good framework, but it's a bit lower level than a canned menu-of-external-commands that you seem to be looking for.

What you're describing sounds very similar to [MythTV's](http://www.mythtv.org/) menus.  You might see how they do it (or even borrow their code, if their license is compatible with yours and if their design is modular enough).

Answer (score 1):

For example: Python + PyQT

Answer (score 0):

I used [pygame](http://www.pygame.org) for a interface that runs fullscreen in framebuffermode and is controllable only using cursor keys

There are also wrappers for ruby, c++, ... if python doesn't suit you well

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, Python + [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/) should work well.